# Only one of the UIView subview showing up?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiview

I want to have one corner `UIView` on every corner of `selected shape`, in the middle of every edge, and one in the center.

`selected shape` has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to it, but when I tap selected shape only the last corner to be placed, [the bottom right corner `bRCorner`, is what shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJQbl.png).

```
class DrawViewController: UIViewController {
     var selectedShape: UIView?
     var tLCorner: UIView?
     var tMCorner: UIView?
     var tRCorner: UIView?
     var mLCorner: UIView?
     var mMCorner: UIView?
     var mRCorner: UIView?
     var bLCorner: UIView?
     var bMCorner: UIView?
     var bRCorner: UIView?

func tapShape(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    selectedShape = sender.view!

    //for each corner: set color, add pan feature, place in view
    var corners = [UIView](count: 9, repeatedValue: UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)))
    for corner in corners{
        corner.backgroundColor = fontColor
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "moveShape:")
        corner.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        self.view.insertSubview(corner, aboveSubview: selectedShape!)
    }

    //place each corner in proper place
    tLCorner = corners[0]
    tLCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.minX)!
    tLCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.minY)!

    tMCorner = corners[1]
    tMCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.midX)!
    tMCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.minY)!

    tRCorner = corners[2]
    tRCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.maxX)!
    tRCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.minY)!

    mLCorner = corners[3]
    mLCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.minX)!
    mLCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.midY)!

    mMCorner = corners[4]
    mMCorner!.center = (selectedShape?.center)!

    mRCorner = corners[5]
    mRCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.maxX)!
    mRCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.midY)!

    bLCorner = corners[6]
    bLCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.minX)!
    bLCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.maxY)!

    bMCorner = corners[7]
    bMCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.midX)!
    bMCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.maxY)!

    bRCorner = corners[8] //the only corner that shows up!
    bRCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.maxX)!
    bRCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.maxY)!
}
```

However when I comment out the last two lines:

```
//bRCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.maxX)!
//bRCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.maxY)!
```

The last corner to be placed becomes the bottom middle corner `bMCorner` and [`bMCorner` is what shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izGVL.png).

```
bMCorner = corners[7] //this is what shows up!
bMCorner!.center.x = (selectedShape?.frame.midX)!
bMCorner!.center.y = (selectedShape?.frame.maxY)!
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening. I would prefer to have all the corners show up. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var corners = [UIView](count: 9, repeatedValue: UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)))
```

That code creates an array of size 9 with `UIView`s inside. But those views are all the exact same object. You only have one `UIView` with 9 references to it basically. Instead move the creation in the loop:

```
var corners = [UIView]()
for var i in 1...9 {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
    corners.append(view)
    // your customization
}
```

You can easily see the difference when you put the following code behind it:
 `corners.forEach { print($0) }`

That prints for your code

> `<UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7fbc2a417100; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbc2a419ce0>>`

=> 9 times the exact **same** memory location / view.

For my code it prints

> `<UIView: 0x7f825b420e60; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b4210e0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b42a6c0; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b401a80>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b612420; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b611180>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b50b960; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b504070>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b50a250; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b611f30>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b511e30; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b50b3e0>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b725110; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b725280>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b613850; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b613500>>
>   <UIView: 0x7f825b727000; frame = (0 0; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f825b724630>>`

=> 9 **different** views.

The apple docs say

> Swift’s Array type also provides an initializer for creating an array of a certain size with **all of its values set to the same default value**. You pass this initializer the number of items to be added to the new array (called count) and a default value of the appropriate type (called repeatedValue):

The bold part is your exact problem here.

Comment: @15ongm you are welcome. I always look through the profiles of low reputation users and look at their questions, answers and upvotes. It seems that you did not make any (or not much) use of your privilege to upvote answers that were helpful. Accepting is for marking on question as solving your problem, upvoting is for giving the author credit for helping you. Additionally on one question you answered yourself - you can accept your own answer there as well.

Comment: I see; I'm new to stack overflow so I'm unfamiliar with the different features. But thank you for letting me know. I'll make sure to make use of the upvote and marking features.

Comment: @15ongm thank you for taking it into account, it is nothing you have to do, but something you should know about.